# Bash array name as variable

Tags: bash

I would like to use array name as variable and pass it to my function.
I'm trying something like this:

```
array_one=(a b c d)
array_two=(1 2 3 4)

function myfunction() {
echo "${$1[*]}" 

}

myfunction array_one 
myfunction array_two
```

I expect result:

```
a b c d
1 2 3 4
```

I'm getting error "bad substitution". Obviously this line is bad:

```
echo "${$1[*]}"
```

How to do it properly?

Comment: I found solution:

  " arr_name="echo \"\${$1[*]}\" "  &&     eval $arr_name} "

Comment: No need for `eval`.